# How to make the ads appear on an activity in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an android activity with a xml layout as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout>
 ...
    <GridLayout>    
    ...
    </GridLayout>
 ....
 </RelativeLayout>
```

to which I would like to add the ads-thingy. I have tried the following setup:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>
     ...
        <GridLayout>    
        ...
        </GridLayout>
     ....
     </RelativeLayout>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    ...
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

but it does not show the ads (the dots represent other content I believe is not important for this question). Is there some special trick to use to be able to show the ads-thingy? Make the layout even more complex? Is there a special layout-things I have to use?

My main activity does show the ads; the structure here is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout>
    ...
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
        <LinearLayout>
        ...
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    ....
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
<LinearLayout
```

A more complete example of the real layout xml file (stripped off the really uneccessary parts...)

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        >

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/new_cancel"
            android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
            android:columnCount="10"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:useDefaultMargins="true">

        // REMOVED TEXTVIEW, EDITTEXT, IMAGEBUTTONS etc HERE

        </GridLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            android:text="Ok"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

P.S. What is the general name of things like `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: Probably the reason lies in the layout widths and heights. Re-post your layouts including the properties 'layout_width', 'layout_height' and 'layout_weight'.

Comment: Please see updated post ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you have to initialize your ad in your Activity code using an AdRequest object:

```
    AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById( R.id.adView );
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
    adView.loadAd( request );
```

Comment: You can read more on this page: http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-how-to-integrate-google-admob-in-your-app/

Comment: That is the solution!!! Of course, how could I forget! There is nothing more complicated than android!! Android is almost as Swisscom. Never mind... I mark your answer as correct...

Answer (score 1):

Discarding a problem with your ADS initialization, as you say it works in another activity, and focusing on layout problems, I'd say the problem is the following:

You have a Vertical LinearLayout that covers the whole screen (match_parent on a top level) with two childs

- The first child is a RelativeLayout that covers the whole parent (match_parent)
- The second child is the Ad View that is probably being displayed, but you can't see it because it starts at the first pixel after the screen height.

So to correct this, I'd suggest you to try:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    >
    .
    .
    .
</RelativeLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

I'd also suggest to give the proper dimensions to the Ad View as you know them (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize#constant-summary) . Then, I'd suggest to use a `FrameLayout` as is way lighter than a `linearlayout`. You would do it like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:layout_marginBottom = "50dp">
        .
        .
        .
     </RelativeLayout>

     <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
     </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: It kind of works. I have an empty space on the button (white) without any text, ads, content...

Comment: well then you need to polish your layout dimensions a little. Have you tried to use the Visual editor in android studio? You should be able to preview the layout

Comment: Well the preview won't show the ads running, but you can see the space reserved for the ad, and check that the dimensions are right, etc. Then at runtime you will see the ad.

Comment: I do not know exactly what to check. On my phone I just see a blank white space ...

Comment: can you change the layout_width of the adview to match_parent? if you still don't see the AD but do see its reserved space there might be a problem initing the ad

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113677/discussion-between-alex-and-rupps).

Comment: Tried several changes, but no luck. But on the main activity I always can see the test ad...

Comment: Maybe I just give up?

Comment: I can try 5 different layouts, that makes 125 different possibilities when using them at three different positions. Then each layout has, say, 10 different attributes with 2 settings each. That makes 1000 possibilities. For a single layout`But I have to try them together. That makes 1000^125 possibilities? The lifetime of the universe is not enough to find a solution by trial...

Comment: I get the feeling developing android apps is just about 'trying' and not actually knowing how it works. Am I mistaken...?

Comment: haha nope, but developing an app involves trying. Your posted layout had a lot of erors, like properties of a relativelayout applied to a linearlayout, incorrect sizes, etc... It helps to read the documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Admob layout is displaying in xml view. Put your admob view inside RelativeLayout and try to use `android:alignparentBottom:true`

You can check this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28578320/2022000

Comment: Make sure you are using correct Admob ID. Check your logcat.